# Get Active Directory GUID from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, active-directory

I'm getting `User GUID` from Active Directory in `C#` using the code below:

```
var GUIDID = "";

using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
{
     using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userNameToUse))
     {
         if (user != null)
         {
            GUIDID = user.Guid.ToString();
         }
     }                           
 }
```

So the output from the code above for a particular person is:

> 7b8b17f1-9997-46ac-bec4-c747eed2de33

What I now want to do is query Active Directory from `SQL Server 2008` using that `GUIDID`. However, the issue I'm running into is I **don't know the name of the column**.

I tried to search for the same person *(using their full name)* from SQL using the code below:

```
SELECT cn, objectGUID
FROM  'LDAP://xxx.local/OU=xxx Users,DC=xxx,DC=xxx'
WHERE objectClass = 'User' AND cn = 'John Smith'
```

Yet, `objectGUID`, `OBjectSID` are not the same as the `GUIDID` my `C#` code is returning.

I also tried to `select *` in my `SQL` query, but it only returns the path.

Any suggestion on how I can find out the `GUID COLUMN name` from SQL Code?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The solution is really simple. I needed to convert the `ObjectID`

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,0xF1178B7B9799AC46BEC4C747EED2DE33);
```

Hope it helps somebody.